# Whats wrong in my code ? 1064 check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a problem in my code
I don't know where the error in my code and I think my code is fine (maybe)

plase help me

this is my code :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dt_training` (
`id_training` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`tanggal` date NOT NULL,
`pm25` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`curahHujan` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`kelembaban` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`kecepatanAngin` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`RESULT` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_training`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=476 ;
INSERT INTO `dt_training` (`id_training`, `tanggal`, `pm25`, `curahHujan`, `kelembaban`, 
`kecepatanAngin`, `RESULT`) VALUES
(1, '2/1/2019', 37.69416376, 1, 78, 2, 0),
(2, '2/2/2019', 27.61848739, 2.3, 70, 3, 0),
(3, '2/8/2019', 34.82260521, 0, 79, 2, 0),
(4, '2/9/2019', 40.56758941, 1.3, 79, 2, 0),
(5, '2/10/2019', 24.05520774, 30.5, 84, 2, 0),
.
.
.
(450, '8/3/2020', 43.53877095, 0, 74, 2, 0),
(451, '8/4/2020', 59.05010846, 0,79, 1, 0),
(452, '8/5/2020', 106.6554527, 14.6, 78, 1, 0),
(453, '8/6/2020', 67.41181118, 0, 75, 2, 0),
(454, '8/7/2020', 62.0547619, 0, 76, 2, 0),
(456, '8/8/2020', 87.904, 0, 76, 2, 0),
(457, '8/9/2020', 69.39713576, 0, 74, 2, 0),
(458, '8/10/2020', 77.89735294, 0, 74, 2, 0),
(459, '8/11/2020', 94.91111111, 0, 78, 0, 0),
(460, '8/12/2020', 58.48239865, 20, 83, 1, 0),
(461, '8/13/2020', 16.5097891, 0, 87, 1, 0),
(462, '8/14/2020', 15.48111111, 2.2, 84, 1, 0),
(463, '8/15/2020', 14.62266776, 3.6, 80, 2, 0),
(464, '8/16/2020', 12.87, 0.8, 79, 2, 0),
(465, '8/17/2020', 10.55883162, 0.4, 75, 2, 0),
(467, '8/18/2020', 14.51629568, 0, 78,1 , 0),
(468, '8/19/2020', 7.316003289, 0, 74, 3, 0),
(469, '8/20/2020', 9.824069767, 0, 70, 2, 0),
(470, '8/26/2020', 0, 0, 58, 4, 0),
(471, '8/27/2020', 0, 0, 63, 3, 0),
(472, '8/28/2020', 0, 0, 67, 3, 0),
(473, '8/29/2020', 0, 0, 74, 2, 0),
(474, '8/30/2020', 0, 0, 70, 2, 0),
(475, '8/31/2020', 0, 0, 66 ,2 , 0);
```

and MYSQL said :

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 469

Comment: Well, those aren't dates, but that wouldn't generate that syntax error (unless MariaDB behaves slightly differently from MySQL in this respect)

Comment: Also, to note that the number in parentheses following an INT declaration is almost meaningless and perhaps best omitted.

Comment: Also, your pm25 column is **int** type, and you are inserting **decimal** values

Comment: Removing the three "." lines the INSERT from the example above fails with `ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '2/1/2019' for column test.dt_training.tanggal at row 1`

So whatever syntax error you have, it has to be in the lines you omitted in this example ...

Comment: Hai Strawberry... Thank you very much for your suggestion

Comment: Oh i see, Thank you nacho for your help

Comment: I am sorry sir, but when i try to dellete the last line ((475, '8/31/2020', 0, 0, 66 ,2 , 0), the error that appears turns  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 468

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
... 1064 ... near ''
```

That usually means that that is an unclosed parenthesis, quote, or other syntax punctuation.  (I don't happen to see such in the snippet you provided; check the rest of the text.)

Other issues.  Use a 1-byte `TINYINT` instead a 4-byte `INT` for flags.

'2/1/2019' is not compatible with `DATE` datatype.  You could use a `str_to_date()` to fix it as you insert the data, or you could change to '2019/02/01'  (Or is it '2019/01/02'??)